# How do i fix Untracked working tree file '._.git'

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Im trying to clone a repository I created a few days ago but I keep getting this error **Untracked working tree file '._.git' would be overwritten by merge.** it also says the the clone was completed but the checkout has failed. I don't have much experience with using git so i'm not sure if this **._.git** file is supposed to be named like that.

Is it not supposed to be **.git**

this happens when ever I create new repositories and i am always having problems when trying to commit files at some point in my development.

I am also using github Desktop because for some reason it wont allow me to the terminal.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Which operating system? macOS?

Comment: yes i am using macOS